# How to change color of link button after postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I'm new to C# and I'm running into the following issues. When I click on the link button(for pagination), it will go to the code behind the page using postback. But the postback will refresh the background color of the button I set on CSS, how should I do?

I used the `ViewState` but it still doesn't work.

What I originally wanted was that when the user presses the paging number, the paging number will display a different color, so that the user can tell which button they are pressing.

Like, when the user press 2, the page will show page 2's details using postback and the paging number at button will show
1 **2** 3 4

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPaging" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptPaging_ItemCommand" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage"
        Style="padding: 8px; margin: 2px; background: lightgray; border: solid 1px #666;font-weight: bold;"
        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" CssClass="listbtn"
        ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True"><%# Container.DataItem %>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

this is the code behind,

```
 public int PageNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
            
    }
        
        set { ViewState["PageNumber"] = value; }
    }
    private int iPageSize = 100;

    private void BindRepeater(DataTable dt)
    {

  
        //Finally, set the datasource of the repeater
        PagedDataSource pdsData = new PagedDataSource();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        pdsData.DataSource = dv;
        pdsData.AllowPaging = true;
        pdsData.PageSize = iPageSize;
        if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
            pdsData.CurrentPageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
        else
            pdsData.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        if (pdsData.PageCount > 1)
        {
            rptPaging.Visible = true;
            ArrayList alPages = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdsData.PageCount; i++)
                alPages.Add((i).ToString());
                 

            rptPaging.DataSource = alPages;
            rptPaging.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            rptPaging.Visible = false;
        }


        rptTxnHist.DataSource = pdsData;
        rptTxnHist.DataBind();
    }
protected void rptPaging_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string sDateFr = datepicker.Value;
        string sDateTo = datepicker2.Value;
        PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
        //ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
   
        LoadUI(PageNumber, "NAME", sDateFr, sDateTo);
    }
```

css code:

```
a:hover, a:focus{
color:white;
background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I read the question to be about a data pager.

But, the goal seems to be just to change the style of a button in the repeater once clicked.

So, assume this repeater:

```
    <style>
        .mylinkbtn {
            padding: 8px;
            margin: 2px; 
            background: lightgray; 
            border: solid 1px #666;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>

    <div style="padding:35px;width:25%">

    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPaging" runat="server"  >  
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <div style="text-align:right">

        <asp:Label ID="lblH" runat="server" Font-Size="14"
            Text= "View Hotel Name ">
        </asp:Label>

        <asp:Label ID="lblHotel" runat="server" Font-Size="14"
            Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' >
        </asp:Label>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage"  CssClass="mylinkbtn"
            runat="server" Text="View"
            ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True"
            OnClick="lnkPage_Click"  > 
        </asp:LinkButton>  

        <br />
        <br />

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:Repeater>
```

This code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }


    void LoadData()
    {
        DataTable rstOptions =
            MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");

        rptPaging.DataSource = rstOptions;
        rptPaging.DataBind();

    }

    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

REMEMBER!!!! - ONLY re-bind the grid ONE time (!IsPostBack). If you leave that bit out, then you are re-binding the repeater and will LOSE your button change of style.

But, a simple post-back WILL NOT re-set the style(s) to apply to any repeated control(s) in the repeater.

So, we get this:

[image]

Now, our button click code. I really DO NOT LIKE the command and button event model for a gridview, listview, repeater etc.

I just drop in a plane jane button, or whatever. Just in the markup type in onclick= (and then space bar - you are promped to create a event click for that button (or any other event). That way you don't have to mess around with row command.

Hence this code:

```
    protected void lnkPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        RepeaterItem rRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;

        int MyRowIndex = rRow.ItemIndex;
        Debug.Print("row index = " + MyRowIndex);
        // get hotel name value
        Label lblHotel = (Label)rRow.FindControl("lblHotel");
        Debug.Print("Row click hotel = " + lblHotel.Text);

        // change button class to show it was clicked 
        btn.CssClass = "btn btn-info";
    }
```

So, for each button I click on, we see this:

[image]

And the output window of the clicks shows this:

[image]

So any style you apply to controls - including that link button will work, and CAN survive a post-back. But, your standard page load event NEAR ALWAYS has to be placed inside of a !IsPostBack stub (last 100+ web pages have such a code stub). In other words, if you re-bind the repeater, then yes of course it will re-plot, re-load, and you lose the style buttons or any other style you applied.

However, since your page !IsPostBack stub on runs on the REAL first page load, then such style settings for buttons controls etc. will persist, and they have automatic view state preserved for you.

So, either you not setting the style to the given row in the repeater, or your page load event is re-binding and re-loading the repeater which of course will blow out and re-set your buttons.

But, for Gridview, repeater, Listview and more such data bound controls? The state of such controls and buttons should persist, assuming you use the all important !IsPostBack code stub (which as I noted, quite much every single page you write will need if you loading up any data bound control(s)).

And as above shows, you are free to have other buttons and have as many post-backs as you wish - the style settings from code behind for those buttons will and should persist.